# resolveInstanceMethod calling from Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can I call `+ (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL` while changing dynamic variable variable name?

E.g.

I've got an ObjC class:

```
    @interface SomeClass: NSObject
    ///
    @end
    @implementation SomeClass: NSObject

     + (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL
    {
    //// code
    }

@end
```

Swift

```
@objcMembers
public final class SomeSwiftClass: SomeClass {
public dynamic var value: NSNumber?
public dynamic func mmFunc() {
        print("mmFunc")
    }
}
```

code:

```
let anInstance = SomeSwiftClass()
anInstance.value = NSNumber(10) /// how can I call resolveInstanceMethod? Doesn't work
anInstance.mmFunc() //doesn't work too.
```

If I implement the same code in ObjC it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to define `mmFunc` with `@objc`: `@objc public dynamic func mmFunc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the following works w/o changes in your classes (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2).

```
func test() {
    let anInstance = SomeSwiftClass()

    let hasMethod = SomeSwiftClass.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(SomeSwiftClass.mmFunc))
    print("Result: \(hasMethod)")

    anInstance.value = NSNumber(10)
    anInstance.mmFunc()
}
```

if not at your side, see if objc-swift bridging is correctly configured and all needed includes are added.

Update: compiler was confused by ambiguous name of `value`, changing it to other more specific name works as below

```c
@interface SomeClass: NSObject
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL isValid;
@end
```

```swift
    @objc
    public class SomeSwiftClass: SomeClass {

    @objc public var specificValue: NSNumber = NSNumber(5)
    @objc public func mmFunc() {
            print("mmFunc")
        }
    }

    @objc
    final class Runner: NSObject {
        @objc public static func test() {
            let anInstance = SomeSwiftClass()

            let hasProperty = SomeSwiftClass.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(getter: SomeSwiftClass.isValid))
            print("Has property: \(hasProperty)")

            let swiftProperty = SomeSwiftClass.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(getter: SomeSwiftClass.specificValue))
            print("Swift property: \(swiftProperty)")

            let hasMethod = SomeSwiftClass.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(SomeSwiftClass.mmFunc))
            print("Has method: \(hasMethod)")

            anInstance.specificValue = NSNumber(10)
            anInstance.mmFunc()
        }
    }
```

Comment: For properties declared in Objective-C - yes, for declared in swift - no.

Comment: I've found. let hasMethod = SomeClass1.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(setter: SomeClass1. value))

Comment: I've created a new similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650794/catch-selector-using-class-addmethod-in-for-swift-classes