# Catch selector using class_addMethod in for swift classes

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've got ObjC class:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *sample;

@end
```

and

```
#import "SomeClass.h"
@import ObjectiveC;

@implementation SomeClass
@dynamic sample;

+ (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL
{
    NSLog(@"resolveInstanceMethod");
    if ([NSStringFromSelector(aSEL) hasPrefix:@"set"])
    {
        class_addMethod([self class], aSEL,
                        (IMP)setPropertyIMP, "v@:@");
    }
    else
    {
        class_addMethod([self class], aSEL,
                        (IMP)propertyIMP, "@@:");
    }
    return YES;
}

static id propertyIMP(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    __block id value = nil;
    NSLog(@"propertyIMP");
    return value;
}

static void setPropertyIMP(id self, SEL _cmd, id aValue)
{
    NSLog(@"setPropertyIMP");
}

@end
```

and its child:

```
@objcMembers
class SomeClass1: SomeClass {
    dynamic var temp = NSNumber(1)

    override init() {
        let setterHasMethod = SomeClass1.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(setter: SomeClass1.temp))
        let getterHasMethod = SomeClass1.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(getter: SomeClass1.temp))
        print("setterHasMethod: \(setterHasMethod)")
        print("getterHasMethod: \(getterHasMethod)")
    }
}
```

So, when I execute this

```
func doSome1() {
        let someInstance = SomeClass1()
        someInstance.temp = NSNumber(2)
        let res = someInstance.temp
        print("res: \(res)")
    }
```

propertyIMP and setPropertyIMP aren't called.

but for `sample`:

```
func doSome() {
        let someInstance = SomeClass1()
        someInstance.sample = NSNumber(2)
        let res = someInstance.sample
        print("res: \(res)")
    }
```

all work correctly.

Is it possible to call methods used in `class_addMethod` for Swift properties?

Comment: No, this is only runtime feature of `Objective-C`, you can try add `@objc` attribute for property.

Comment: @Cy-4AH do you have any proof?

Comment: Proof is that your's code does't work?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I've found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@NSManaged` instead of `dynamic`:

```
@objcMembers
class SomeClass1: SomeClass {
    @NSManaged var temp = NSNumber(1)

    override init() {
        let setterHasMethod = SomeClass1.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(setter: SomeClass1.temp))
        let getterHasMethod = SomeClass1.resolveInstanceMethod(#selector(getter: SomeClass1.temp))
        print("setterHasMethod: \(setterHasMethod)")
        print("getterHasMethod: \(getterHasMethod)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just implement `didSet`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH because of the library I use